# Installing packages manually (lccaps)

Tags: packages, installing

Hi I am new to LaTeX and I have a little problem regarding the installation of a package manually. I downloaded a template to write my thesis and on the first run of it I clicked through all the automatic installations of packages. Some didn't work so I planned to install them manually. I could do that for all of them except for one package named `lccaps`. The other files I downloaded existed already as `.sty` files and I could just place them in my folder. This was not the case for the `lccaps`, this was one `.ins` file and one `.dtx` file. I got all the files from CTAN and I tried to run them using `cmd.exe` and this command:

```
latex H:\MYPATH\lccaps.ins
```

according to the istructions in the readme.

```
To install the package

 1. run `latex lccaps.ins`
 2. move 'lccaps.sty' to locations where LaTeX will find it
```

But I receive an error message saying it couldn't find the `lccaps.dtx` file (see image).
[image]
But the file is there and in the same folder as the `.ins` file I am trying to run. What am I doing wrong? Is there a special folder in the Latex installation (I am using Miktex and TeXWorks as editor) I have to use?

Comment: Copy the .ins and the dtx in the current folder (C:\users\XXX) and then call `latex lccaps.ins` and not `latex some/long/path/.../`